# Select span of sibling div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery selectors, and I need to be able to find each span individually that contains a dollar amount. For example, I'd like to find & change the first `span` to $15 and the third `span` to $40. I have put in class names in my example, but in my problem I do not know the class names, and I do not know which span the 2nd dollar amount is in. There also could be more or less div's and spans.

This happens to be in a form, and I find the first dollar amount like this:

```
$("form[action='/cart'] span:contains('$'):first).replaceWith("$15");
```

I have the following HTML.

```
<div class="daddy">
  <div class="kid1">
    <span>$10</span>
  </div>
  <div class="kid2">
    <span>Nothing to see here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="kid3">
    <span>$20</span>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know a selector to select all of the spans at once?

Comment: No, I don't want to select all the spans, as I have to change them individually.. I have to select the first and change it, then find the next span with a `$` amount and select it.. Unless I can step through all the spans after I select them?

Comment: Could you not just remove the `:first` and then use `forEach`? Or perhaps `nth-of-type` instead of `:first`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not having an array with values to be updated and query the span which contains `'$'` and update accordingly?

```js
var ratesToUpdate = [15, 40, 70];

var spans = $("form[action='/cart'] span:contains('$')");

spans.each(function(index, span){
$(span).text('$'+ratesToUpdate[index]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/cart">
  <div class="daddy">
    <div class="kid1">
      <span>$10</span>
    </div>
    <div class="kid2">
      <span>Nothing to see here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="kid3">
      <span>$20</span>
    </div>
    <div class="kid4">
      <span>nothing</span>
    </div>
    <div class="kid5">
      <span>nothing</span>
    </div>
    <div class="kid5">
      <span>$50</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this one.. let me see

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over each `span` element and check if it's `innerHTML` contains `$` symbol. If so, return all these `span`s and their position (`index`).

Once you have their `index` position, you can modify them as you like.

**Note**: No `jQuery` needed in this solution.

**Example**: You can push every `index` of each matched `span` to an array. In this particular case, it would look like `var matchedIndexes = [0, 2]`. Then basically, if you want to change e.g. the first element - simply use `matchedIndexes[0]`.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    matchedIndexes = [];
    Array.from(elems).forEach(function(v,i){
      if (/\$/.test(v.innerHTML)){
        matchedIndexes.push(i);
      }
    });

//change html of the first element
elems[matchedIndexes[0]].innerHTML = '$15'; 

//or change the last matched element
elems[matchedIndexes[matchedIndexes.length-1]].innerHTML = '$99';
```

```html
<div class="daddy">
  <div class="kid1">
    <span>$10</span>
  </div>
  <div class="kid2">
    <span>Nothing to see here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="kid3">
    <span>$20</span>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `.includes()`, I would suggest using `.indexOf()`. IE and I believe Edge still don't support it. EDIT: Much better. :)

Comment: @DrewKennedy Great idea, but instead of `.indexOf()`, I'd prefer `test()` with `RegExp` (:

Answer (score 0):

Would this solve your problem?

```
var values = [15, 40];
$("form[action='/cart'] span:contains('$')").each(
    function(index, element)
    {
        element.value = '$'+ values[index];
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer `Kind user` gave - but here is my stab at it. I couldn't make it more dynamic as the addition values are not similar (first one is added by 5, third is doubled...)

JSFiddle Here: https://jsfiddle.net/rL36jv8m/

Your HTML

```
<div class="daddy">
  <div class="kid1">
    <span>$10</span>
  </div>
  <div class="kid2">
    <span>Nothing to see here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="kid3">
    <span>$20</span>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Array of addition values to corresponding divs.

```
var addValues = [
    5,
  '',
  20
]
```

Iteration:

```
$('.daddy').children().each(function(i, o) {
    var elem = $(o).find('span');
    if (elem.html().indexOf('$') === 0) {
    elem.html('$' + (parseInt(elem.html().replace('$', '')) + addValues[i]))
  }
})
```

Hope this helps.